# Where is the Glassfish 4 upgrade tool

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-4

I am trying to upgrade Glassfish 3.1.2.2 to 4.0 and according to the instructions the I should use the Upgrade tool. I have downloaded the glassfish zip and the upgrade tool is nowhere to be found. I have also looked in the update tool and it is not there.

Anyone know where I can find it?

Answer (score -1):

It is in the `bin` folder...

But updating Glassfish 3 to Glassfish 4 doesn't make sense...just get Glassfish 4 from [the official download site](https://glassfish.java.net/download.html).

Comment: I can not find the upgrade tool in that folder. What name do see it as?

Comment: And you find it in the glassfish zipfile here http://download.java.net/glassfish/4.0/release/glassfish-4.0.zip? What path?

Comment: i unzip the file and in the bin folder in the root dir there is only asadmin pkg and updatetool, in glassfish/bin there is appclient, asadmin capture-schema jspc package-appclient schemagen startserv stopserv wscompile wsdeploy wsgen wsimport xjc. But you say that when you unzip that file you find a upgradetool in the bin folder?

Comment: @unwichtich: The question asked for the upGRADE tool, not the upDATE tool. @ all: According to some Glassfish 3.1 documentation, the upgrade tool should be bin/asupgrade. I heard it never worked properly. I guess they have simply given up trying to make it work and didn't update the documentation accordingly.