# Upgrading from Glassfish 2.1.1 to Glassfish 4.1

Tags: migration, glassfish-4.1, glassfish-2.x

Can someone please enlighten me. I'm trying to upgrade my Glassfish 2.1.1 to Glassfish 4.1. I've decided to do a side by side install as indicated here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24942/upgrading-legacy-installation.htm#GSUPG00039

Question are: 
**(1) What is "as-install"?** There's no such directory as-install\bin in my extracted glassfish4 so I assumed it is the installation directory? Is it glassfish4\bin or glassfish4\glassfish\bin?

**(2) I can't see the asupgrade.bat file in my glassfish 4.1** so I'm not able to proceed with the steps on the above link. I'm not sure if the version is related since the document specifically says "upgrade to GlassFish Server 3.1". I can see a pkg directory, and there's also an updatetool.bat. I can't run the upgrade tool though since I'm in a closed environment (no internet).

(3) **Is it okay to just delete the Sun folder (for Sun Glassfish Enterprise Server v2.1.1) and replace it with the glassfish4 folder (for Glassfish4.1)?** Then I will just run my updated installer that supports the new server. Fresh install works, however we also want to try upgrade.

(4) Assuming #3 is not possible, are there any other way?

Sorry to ask this here since I'm not familiar to any Oracle/Sun community. Google search' top results doesn't specifically answer these questions.

**UPDATE:** Apparently, I found a similar unanswered thread here: [Where is the Glassfish 4 upgrade tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066992/where-is-the-glassfish-4-upgrade-tool) . Same issue, upgradetool is no where to be found. Also, tried to connecting to internet and I still can't update it via updatetool.bat.

**UPDATE2:** Apparently, updatetool.bat doesn't work for Glassfish4.1. I tried running it/installing it so that the upgradetool might be visible but it seems it can't download the application packages.